# Stick-breaking construction of Dirichlet distribution vs Dirichlet process

Tags: probability, references, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

Let $F_0$ be some probability measure and $\alpha > 0$ be the concentration parameter. I can draw a random distribution from $F\sim \mathrm{DP}(\alpha, F_0)$ using the stick-breaking construction:
\begin{align*}
v_k &\sim \mathrm{Beta}(1, \alpha)\\
\phi_k &\sim F_0\\
\pi_k &= v_k \prod_{j < k} (1-v_j)\\
F &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \pi_k \delta_{\phi_k}.
\end{align*}

Now consider a finite-dimensional Dirichlet distribution with $K$ classes. If I draw a random distribution $F^K$ according to the following model:
\begin{align*}
\pi' &\sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha/K, \cdots, \alpha/K)\\
\phi'_k &\sim F_0\\
F^K &\sim \sum_{k=1}^K \pi'_k \delta_{\phi'_k},
\end{align*}
then for every function $f$ integrable with respect to $F_0$ it holds that the sequence of random variables $\mathbb E_{F^K}[f]$ converge in distribution to $\mathbb E_F[f]$ as $K\to \infty$.

---

Hence, I'd naively expect that several entries of $\pi'$ for very large $K$ should be approximately the same as several entries of $\pi$.

However, I have a trouble to understand why it mathematically would be the case.
Recall that sampling $\pi'\sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha/K, \cdots, \alpha/K)$ can be accomplished by a stick-breaking construction (valid for $k = 1, \dotsc, K-1$):
\begin{align*}
u_k & \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha/K, \alpha\cdot (1-k/K) )\\
\pi'_k &= u_k \prod_{j<k} (1-u_j)
\end{align*}

For $k \ll K$ I have $1-k/K \approx 1$ and this stick-breaking construction looks deceptively similar, apart from the fact that I sample from
$$u_k \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha/K, \alpha)$$
rather than
$$v_k \sim \mathrm{Beta}(1, \alpha)$$
used in the stick-breaking process of the Dirichlet process.

I have been thinking quite a lot about this discrepancy and I realized that as I have a *symmetric* distribution $\mathrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha/K, \cdots, \alpha/K)$, there is no reason why e.g., $\pi'_1$ should match as $\pi_1$ (rather than, say, $\pi'_5$).
Hence, the stick-breaking process of $\pi'$ above doesn't really mimic well the strick-breaking process used to sample $\pi$.

I have tried to read [J. Pitman's "Random Discrete Distributions Invariant under Size-Biased Permutation"](https://doi.org/10.2307/1428070), but I have not really understood how to improve the stick-breaking process of $u_k$ to make it size-biased.

Hence, my question is:

> Is there a size-biased stick-breaking construction of the symmetric Dirichlet distribution which would mimic the one of Dirichlet process?

References studying this construction would be very welcome!